# openjdk-8 for Debian 10

Tags: debian, openjdk

I need to install openjdk-8 on a docker container based on the latest python image (debian 10), but the openjdk-8-jdk package has been removed from the stable debian repository. 
I've already tried the usual
`apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
and `apt-cache search openjdk` only returns the openjdk-11.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031649/how-to-install-openjdk-8-jdk-on-debian-10-buster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by manually downloading the packages with **wget**:

```
RUN wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb
```

and then install it using the **dkpg** with the **-i --force-all** options to install all the required dependencies:

```
RUN dpkg -i --force-all openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jre_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk_8u212-b03-2~deb9u1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I can't download `Connecting to security-cdn.debian.org (security-cdn.debian.org)|151.101.36.204|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa the packages have been updated. These are the new packages available: `http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u232-b09-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb`.
You can find all of them here: [debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/openjdk-8)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436618/400544) is nicer:

```
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot
```

Answer (score 1):

As "addon" to the answer of Emil Chitas using **wget**:

- Check the [debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/openjdk-8) site for the current version (e.g. `8u275-b01-1~deb9u1`)
- Copy the version string and set environment-variable before download
- start download
- install

Download with:

```
VER=8u275-b01-1~deb9u1 \
ARCH=amd64 \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_${VER}_${ARCH}.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_${VER}_${ARCH}.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_${VER}_${ARCH}.deb \
&& wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_${VER}_${ARCH}.deb
```

Install with:

```
dpkg -i --force-all openjdk-8*
```